# Submit and Cancel Button not working in react google picker

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api, google-picker

Submit, Cancel, close Buttons are not working in react google picker ,  But can select file by double clicking the file

[image: bug image]

```
import GooglePicker from "react-google-picker";

<GooglePicker
  clientId={"**********"}
  developerKey={"*********"}
  scope={["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"]}
  onChange={(data) => googleDriveFilePicked(data)}
  onAuthenticate={(token) => { setToken(token) }}
  onAuthFailed={(data) => console.log("on auth failed:", data)}
  multiselect={false}
  navHidden={false}
  authImmediate={false}
  mimeTypes={["application/pdf", "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"]}
  viewId={"DOCS"}
>
  <Button className="drive-logo-section" <img alt="Google" src={Google} />
  </Button>
</GooglePicker>
```

git link :  https://github.com/sdoomz/react-google-picker/issues/38

Comment: is the event being received?

Comment: yes, i can select the file and access file data by double clicking the file.

git issue link https://github.com/sdoomz/react-google-picker/issues/38

Comment: Can you see any errors in the developper console in the browser?

Comment: No errors in console.